# New bevel method?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

Is it possible to have a bevel modifier on an object, that has special behavior for vertices? Essentially, instead of truncating the corner, it would merge the bevels of the converging edges into a point. Here's a quick example that I manually created:[image: a cube mockup]
[image: another angle of the default cube, in edit mode]
EDIT: as per request, here's the cube, with segments 2 and 3.
[image: cube with 2 segment bevel]
[image: cube with 3 segment bevel]
If this isn't possible, how would I go about suggesting it?

Comment: can you provide some examples of how it should look with more than one segment?

Comment: Well, Blender is open source so if you can code it you could try to create your own version of the bevel tool... otherwise you have to contact the developers and ask them to implement it. Since I have no idea how complicated this is I doubt they will do it for a single request. And the question of @ShantanuAryan is valid, too. You can increase the segments of a bevel, with one it looks simple and logical, but how is this supposed to be with more segments?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for the info. I just added more examples with more segments. As you mentioned, I think it looks cleanest at only 1 segment, and that's how I imagine it'd be used, but it's fully possible with higher amounts as well.

Comment: This particular effect could be easy to implement. You basically do normal Bevel, then subdivide the short corner edges and move the point in the middle up/down. And merge the two vertices with it. On a cube no problem I guess, the indexing of vertices stays, but when it comes to other shapes and deciding where is up/down (as it is not symetrical) it could get pretty difficult fast.